# Hair particle system not applying correctly

Tags: particles

[image]
[image]
so as shown in the images, when I have the particle on without applying it, its working fine, but once I apply it the hair disappears, any solutions?

I tried increasing and decreasing the amount of hair on the mesh, but it didn't work, in addition to checking on the diameter and other settings but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to apply the *Particle Systen* modifier? As far as I know this is normal behavior that the hair disappears when it is applied because the particles are not a mesh. You can use the *Convert To Mesh* button to create a mesh from it. But usually this results in a high-poly mesh with a lot of vertices.

Comment: It's because i want to join the legs with the main body so its easier to rig, I guess, I'll just keep it as it is and find someway to rig it. Thank you!

Comment: For animation in Blender, keep the Particle System and don't apply the modifier. You can join the mesh objects. Just keep in mind that only the modifiers of the active object (highlighted in orange) are kept. The areas for the hair can be controlled with a vertex group ("weight painting"). Set this vertex group for *Density* or *Length* in the *Particle Properties* tab > *Vertex Groups* section.

Comment: You're right that's way easier, didn't know how to use weight painting till now, thanks to you :D